# Cakephp 2 jquery post request

Tags: php, jquery, cakephp

I would like to make web service which will delete post asynchronusly. I am not sure how to create request in jquery.

This is how I am working now, and it doesn't work

```
$(".delete-link").live("click", function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var id = $(this).attr("id");
        $.post("app/posts/deleteAjax/", {"id": id}, function(data){
            console.log(data);
        });
    });
```

My link has class "delete-link". I created function deleteAjax with parameter ID in file PostsController.php

Cake gives me error that it can't find file. I am not sure how should I make a call properly and how to handle it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try giving full path to url like,

```
$.post("<?php echo $this->webroot; ?>posts/deleteAjax/", {"id": id}, function(data){
 ...
```

Added
If js extension file, then you can define webroot in your **layout.ctp** and use it in your .js file, like in your default.ctp:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var webroot = '<?php echo $this->webroot; ?>';
//now you can use webroot to get full path
</script>
```

Hope it helps

Comment: I can't put full path because I put that jquery in file with js extension.

Comment: Ok, now I added webroot  to post request. But I still have the same error.
POST http://127.0.0.1/cakephp/app/posts/deleteAjax/ 404 (Not Found)

Comment: should be webroot/yourControllerName/controllerfunctionName ... did you do it in the similar way.. because i see your url has cakephp/apps/posts/deleteAjax, i think that's the problem

Comment: that was the answer :) I put apps in my path
do you know some  good manual for using jquery advanced functions with cake?